# Clojure load-file on repl and call -main with arguments

Tags: clojure, program-entry-point

I've done some coding in clojure inside core.clj which have a -main method that can take 0 or more arguments:

```
(defn -main
  "dequeue function"
   [& args]
```

I'm loading this clj file with:

```
(load-file "src/exercise/core.clj")
```

And then i'm trying to learn how to call this within repl in order to develop core_test.clj (if there is any tips about how to develop this auto tests, please give me some hints as well). What I'm trying to do now is:

```
(-main "resources\\sample-input.json" "a")
```

But this is printing "**Arguments 0**" which is a message that I told the code to print just to see how many arguments are being passed with

```
(println "Arguments" (count *command-line-args*))
```

How am I suposed to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i'm trying to learn how to call this within repl in order to develop core_test.clj

Usually you'd write other functions that are called from `-main` and test those rather than the app's entry point `-main`.

But you *should* be able to call `-main` like any other function. I have a `src/sandbox/main.clj` file:

```
(ns sandbox.main)
(defn -main [& args]
  (prn args))
```

Starting a REPL in the project folder, I can call `-main` like this:

```
(use 'sandbox.main) ;; (load-file "src/sandbox/main.clj") also works
=> nil
(in-ns 'sandbox.main)
=> #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x67ccce04 "sandbox.main"]
(-main "some" "args")
;; ("some" "args")
=> nil
```

There's a key difference in my example though: it's printing `-main`'s `args` binding; `*command-line-args*` is nil because you're not running the code from the command line with args, you're running it from a REPL.

Regardless, it's probably a better idea to use an [existing library to work with CLI args](https://github.com/clojure/tools.cli) rather than `*command-line-args*` directly.

Comment: Soo... I've just changed *command-line-args* with args (which make a lot more sense) and now I can call both -main and "lein run" just fine... This resolved the issue! Thanks a lot @Taylor Wood